# How many turns it takes to cats in a chessboard jumps to the same square?

Tags: probability

How can I solve this one? Ten cats are on the chessboard, every cat is on one of the square and the can be on the same square as well as in a different square. Every turn each cat jumps to the adjacent square with equal probability. They won't jump outside the board. So in the corner a cat can jump to three squares with each jump happens with probability $1/3$ and on the center of the board with probability $1/8$. How many turns it takes on average that all cats are on the same square?

Comment: I think: 1. Calculate stationary probability distribution for cat to be on each square. Use symmetry to reduce calculation from 64 probabilities to only 16.  2. Say probability for square $i$ is $p_i$.  Then probability of all cats on same square is $p=\sum_{i=1}^{64} p_i^{10}$. 3.Expected number of turns is $\frac1p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three different types of squares:

1) $6\times6=36$ central squares, each reachable from 8 different directions. Denote the probability of a cat taking a central square with $p_1$.

2) $4\times6=24$ edge squares, each reachable from 5 different directions. The probability of a cat taking an edge square is $p_2=\frac58p_1.$

3) $4$ corner squares, each reachable from 3 different directions. The probability of a cat taking a corner square is $p_3=\frac38p_1$.

Sum of all proabilities has to be equal to 1:

$$36p_1+24\times\frac58p_1+4\times\frac38p_1=1$$

...which implies:

$$p_1=\frac{2}{105},\quad p_2=\frac{1}{84}, \quad p_3=\frac{1}{140}$$

The probability that 10 cats will end up on the same square is:

$$P=36p_1^{10}+24p_2^{10}+4p_3^{10}$$

Expected number of turns $E$ is:

$$E=\frac{1}{P}=\frac{1}{36p_1^{10}+24p_2^{10}+4p_3^{10}}=\frac{1}{36\left(\frac{2}{105}\right)^{10}+24\left(\frac{1}{84}\right)^{10}+4\left(\frac{1}{140}\right)^{10}}=4.392\times10^{15}$$

Assuming that cat needs one second to do the jump, we'll have to wait about 140 million years before all cats jump to the same square at the same time :)

**EDIT:** To confirm probabilities $p_1$, $p_2$ and $p_3$ I have made a simulation with a single cat making one billion random jumps on a chessboard. Here is the number of visits the cat made to each square:

```
   7143004   11912628   11903356   11905677   11900317   11904718   11910367    7145275 
  11907889   19060966   19055158   19043601   19046747   19047165   19046961   11914199 
  11912438   19052604   19048672   19048660   19047571   19058482   19049581   11903917 
  11906619   19048517   19047432   19055252   19053011   19045127   19044827   11897243 
  11900140   19042740   19047619   19048125   19040301   19042256   19043828   11901244 
  11903306   19038343   19042442   19045611   19044110   19053048   19048414   11907292 
  11901422   19044287   19039872   19045175   19046148   19049024   19048627   11904469 
   7139570   11907338   11901830   11895860   11905404   11904611   11907035    7142529
```

The above values agree with calculated values beautifully.

**EDIT 2:** I was curios to see what happens if cat's movements are restricted so that only horizontal or vertical jumps are allowed (no diagonal moves at all). My gut feeling was that the cats will meet faster if you restrict their movements but I was wrong (if my calculations were correct, of course). "Meeting time" almost doubled to 280 million years :)

Comment: If the cats are only allowed to jump to horizontal or vertical neighbouring squares then each cat always jumps from a white square to a black square or vice versa. If a cat starts on a black square then it will always be on a white square after an odd number of jumps and on a black square after an even number of jumps. So if two cats start on squares of different colours then they can never meet.

Comment: @gandalf61 If "turn" means that all cats have to jump simultaneously, you are right. A "white" cat will never meet a "black" cat. However, If "turn" means that each cat has to jump once in sequential or random order (not simultaneously), the cats could still meet.